# how to check file existance without loading it in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, file, actionscript, external

i wanna put a button for downloading a file using navigateURL which is working when the file is around and when its not its gonna shows the 404 stuff. i wanna make the swf check if that file is not where it should be then just do the visible.false on the button, the problem is i don't know how to check it without loading the file.
i'll appreciate your help.

Additional :
its a web app and the button gonna simply open a link in a browser which gonna be a mp3 file and a pdf file. thats how i let the user download them.

Comment: Is this a web app, mobile app, AIR app? It's going to be a different answer depending on what platform you are targeting.

Comment: navigateURL? What about using FileLoaderUtils.doesFileExist(url:String) http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?328651-Checking-to-see-if-a-file-exists-before-loading

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to get some 'init data' from web server. Which should contain information about files. But also you can catch Loader's `Event.OPEN`. If it's caught - file exists and then call `close` method, if not then you will catch `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR`.

[The open event is dispatched when loading begins.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)